# Strong limit cardinal - power set operation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Strong limit cardinal is defined as some cardinal that cannot be reached by power set operation - but $2^{\aleph_0}$, strong limit cardinal, can be reached by power set of $\aleph_0$! So there must be something I am misunderstanding.

Comment: In all seriousness, and without trying to mock or something, why did you think that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a strong limit cardinal?

Comment: @AsafKaragila misunderstanding. You are righteous(?) to mock to me... :( Oh well.

Comment: I'm not trying to mock you, we all have to start somewhere, and everyone had the wrong idea about something "obvious" at one point or another. It's called being a student, and even as one progresses in life, one is always a student, learning new things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\beth_1=2^{\aleph_0}$ is not a strong limit cardinal. $\beth_0=\aleph_0$ is a strong limit cardinal, as is $\beth_\omega$; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cardinal).